# why get request is not respond anything in php

Tags: php

i am trying to get data from a website 
`https://api.timescoaching.in/v1/courses` but my php code is not return anything.And when i open this url `https://api.timescoaching.in/v1/courses` in browser it working fine. I am sharing my php code please correct if there is any mistake

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://api.timescoaching.in/v1/courses');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: In your php.ini file, is allow_url_fopen set to on?

Comment: Enable proper PHP error reporting first of all. And then, do a `var_dump($homepage);` instead of an echo.

Comment: please edit my code so that it echo url result

Comment: `var_dump($homepage);` is responding `bool(false)`

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to come to get your code written for you, it's more about helping you understand why your code isn't working and point you in the right direction to a working solution.

Comment: so sir please tell me why it not working

Comment: Look at my first comment, you haven't responded: 'In your php.ini file, is allow_url_fopen set to on?'

Comment: i don't have any `php.ini` file and site which i am talking is hosted on another server

Comment: you DO have a php.ini

Comment: Use <?php phpinfo(); ?> to get information about your php.ini

Comment: I tried you code and I get this warning,
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.timescoaching.in/v1/courses): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: no error with url when open in any broswer but having problem with php

Comment: Have you tried another URL to be certain that the code isn't working? It could be the page you are trying to connect to that it's not working properly

Comment: https://api.timescoaching.in/v1/courses

Comment: add this to your php file, above your code after 
<?php

ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);

ini_set('display_errors',1);

error_reporting(-1);

Comment: open my comment url it working fine. Please try from your end

Comment: it is working in the browser, yes I know,

Comment: so why not working in php code

Comment: I have tried also this code,

<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);


function url_get_contents ( $url ) {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'curl_init' ) ) {
        die( 'The cURL library is not installed.' );
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $output = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $output;
}


$homepage = url_get_contents('https://api.timescoaching.in/v1/courses');
var_dump($homepage);
?>
didn't work

Comment: can you tell me where is the problem

Comment: i done a curl call and their .NET stuff is throwing an exception

Comment: is their any solution

Comment: I don't think so? Their stuff seems broke, look here https://3v4l.org/ED5e0

Comment: try this code and you can see for yourself https://3v4l.org/FNUiE

Answer (score 0):

If the site is hosted on a server and you have access to the php.ini file then change the value of allow_url_fopen = On; .Your error will be fixed , this error generates when the default value of allow_url_fopen is set to zero which does not allow any data interaction or url interaction with other urls .

Comment: i am not owner of this website. This is not hosted by me. I am only  trying to get data.

Comment: In such a case you wont be able to pull in data because when your generating a request for data pulling through another url allow_url_fopen needs to be on otherwise file_get_contents wont work .